# Automatically pretty format large number of Java source files

Tags: java, netbeans, autoformatting

I have many Java files from a project which have not been formatted properly. Also due to enforcement of a common style many people have introduced their own coding style. I want to bring all this code to one consistent format. Are there any auto-formatters available which I can run as script on all the files. I would like to rethink and fine tune following options:

1. Number of spaces used for indentation.
2. Spaces around operators like + - * / etc.
3. Separation between parentheses.
4. etc.

I was looking at Netbeans auto format and looked cool. Moreover the parameters can be set from the option dialog. However I am not able to completely grasp how to use the API

Comment: Why do you need to use the API?  In IntelliJ you can take the whole OpenJDK in one project and reformat everything with one command. Once it is formatted you don't need to do it again. (IntelliJ also support auto-formatting on each check in so its still formatted when changed)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Eclipse `JavaCodeFormatter` from the command line:

> The following example runs the formatting of code specified by the
>   configuration file `D:/formatter.prefs` on the files Java belonging
>   (directly or indirectly) to the directory `D:/tmp/src` :
>
> ```
> eclipse -application org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -config D:/formatter.prefs D:/tmp/src
> ```

See http://wiyoo.blogspot.com/2007/05/batch-formatting-java-source-code-with.html for details.

Comment: I was looking for Netbeans based solution as I use it as my IDE, but this solution is well and good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if you use eclipse, but to do spacing and parenthasis you just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> and to do auto indentation is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why use the API? Bring it in as a NetBeans project. Same with Eclipse or IntelliJ; they can all format all source files in a project.

For standalone, try [Jalopy](http://jalopy.sourceforge.net/). It can also be set up to run as part of a build, as a commit hook, etc.

Comment: I had no idea how Netbeans could format all source files in a project until I found this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/18365 - Is that what you were referring to regarding Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Try [JIndent](http://www.jindent.com/). Or here're a [bunch](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-beautifiers) of open source code formatters for Java, some of them can be run as standalone products, others as plugins inside an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans).

Comment: Here's the [JIndent licensing info](http://www.jindent.com/products/source-code-formatter-for-java-c-cpp/license).